# join two data frames based on user defined function

Tags: r, join, data.table, plyr, dplyr

I'm trying to (inner) join two data frames based on a similarity function that I have.
for example:

```
data1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),lat=c(38.862976,37.878146,36.825658), lon=c(-99.336782,-99.326054,-98.475976))
data2<-data.frame(b=c(10,20),lat=c(38.863412,37.877333), lon=c(-99.336701,-99.325151))
```

and given a similarity function:

```
are.close(lat1,long1,lat2,long2)
```

something like

```
data3<-join(a=data1,b=data2,by=c(lat,lon),FUN=are.close(a.lat,a.lon,b.lat,b.lon))
```

The output I wish to receive is:

```
  a b  lat        lon
1 1 10 38.862976 -99.336782
2 2 20 37.878146 -99.326054
```

Where the lat/lon belongs to one of the tables (it doesn't matter which, say the first).

All the join/merge methods I checked doesn't let you define how the join is taking place. It only lets you specify things like col1=col2.

Is there a way to do this computationally efficient (not by running with two loops on the two sets)?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using `outer` to identify (a,b) pairs that meet the criterion:

```
neighbormat <- outer(
  1:nrow(data1),
  1:nrow(data2),
  function(i1,i2){  
    are.close(
      data1$lat[i1],
      data1$lon[i1],
      data2$lat[i2],
      data2$lon[i2]
    )
  }
)
dimnames(neighbormat) <- list(data1$a,data2$b)
```

Using the names only makes sense if `a` and `b` are unique, but I'll assume they are since the OP is using them that way. For @konvas's `are.close` function, this gives

```
     10    20
1  TRUE  TRUE
2  TRUE  TRUE
3 FALSE FALSE
```

To get the (a,b) pairs that meet the criterion, use

```
ns <- which(neighbormat,arr.ind=TRUE,use.names=TRUE)
dimnames(ns) <- list(NULL,c("a","b"))

     a b
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 2 1
[3,] 1 2
[4,] 2 2
```

It's straightforward to merge these back to the original data. (Taking an arbitrary (lat,lon) as the OP does, seems like a very bad idea, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `dplyr`. I have assumed that `are.close()` is vectorised and returns `TRUE/FALSE`, for example this will work with a function like `are.close <- function(a, b, c, d) (a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2 < 1`

```
library(dplyr)
expand.grid(a = data1$a, b = data2$b) %>%
    left_join(data1, by = "a") %>%
    left_join(data2, by = "b") %>%
    mutate(close = are.close(lat.x, lon.x, lat.y, lon.y)) %>%
    filter(close)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know of a function that does this (but there of course might be...), so I would try writing some code myself. Which might be difficult depending on the data. But assuming that couples are really clear (e.g. the latitude of point 1 could be closest to b 10, whereas the longitude might be closer to b 20, etc.) this might be the beginning of something to work with:

```
data1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),lat=c(38.862976,37.878146,36.825658), lon=c(-99.336782,-99.326054,-98.475976))
data2<-data.frame(b=c(10,20),lat=c(38.863412,37.877333), lon=c(-99.336701,-99.325151))

# calculate which is the closest value
names(data1)=c("a","lat_original","lon_original")
closest=function(x,to=to) to[which.min(abs(to - x))]
data1$lat=sapply(data1$lat_original,function(x) closest(x,to=data2$lat))
data1$lon=sapply(data1$lon_original,function(x) closest(x,to=data2$lon))

# if dataframes are not equally big: remove biggest assigned "closest values" (or doubles?)
if(nrow(data1)!=nrow(data2)) {
  data1$diff=abs(data1$lat-data1$lat_original)+abs(data1$lon-data1$lon_original)
  maxN <- function(x, N=N){
  x=x[!is.na(x)]
  len=length(x)
  if(N>len){
    warning('N greater than length(x).  Setting N=length(x)')
    N=length(x)
  }
  sort(x,partial=len-N+1)[as.numeric(len-N+1):len]
}
data1=data1[!data1$diff %in% maxN(data1$diff,N=nrow(data1)-nrow(data2)),]}

# perhaps check if doubles (two different points of data 1 assigned to the same point in data2)
which(duplicated(paste(data1$lat,data1$lon))==T)

#merge based on those closest values
merge(data1,data2,by=c("lat","lon"))
```